# How to group two nested lists among themselves in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two nested lists :

```
list1=[['AH_ID', -20000, 'First'],['HT_ID', -20000, 'Second'],['YE_ID', -20000, 'First']]
list2=[['AH_ID', -30000, 'First'],['ZZ_ID', -20000, 'Third'],['YE_ID', 17000, 'Second']]
```

I want to group their nested lists in this way:

first: group by the first element of the list (they serve me as id), if the ID is the same in the two lists, only the subsequent elements change.

second: subsequent elements must be changed to elements from the list2.

third: output all nested lists (without changing them), if their ID does not match.

I would like to get this output.

```
final_list=[['AH_ID', -30000, 'First'],['HT_ID', -20000, 'Second'],['YE_ID', 17000, 'Second'],['ZZ_ID', -20000, 'Third']]
```

I think, should I use a dictionary to group nested lists by their first element?

I tried to use the **set** method, but I didn’t manage to do what I want.

Comment: So for common first element in the sublists, the e.g `'AH_ID'` which element will be picked up ?

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh in list1

Comment: Then why `'YE_ID', 17000, 'Second']` is picked up when it is in `list2` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a dictionary, the key management is much easier there:
Check this code out:

```
# returns a sublist based on a key match
 def sublist_fromkey(list, key):
    for sublist in list:
        if sublist[0] == key:
            return sublist
    return []

def main():
    list1=[['AH_ID', -20000, 'First'],['HT_ID', -20000, 'Second'],['YE_ID', -20000, 'First']]
    list2=[['AH_ID', -30000, 'First'],['ZZ_ID', -20000, 'Third'],['YE_ID', 17000, 'Second']]
    # stores keys for each list
    l1_keys=[]
    l2_keys=[]
    # final list is contents of list2 and anything unique on list1
    final_list=list2
    # populate keys for each list
    for x in list1:
        l1_keys.append(x[0])
    for x in list2:
        l2_keys.append(x[0])
    # find anything unique in list1 and add it
    for key_1 in l1_keys:
        if key_1 not in l2_keys:
                final_list.append(sublist_fromkey(list1,key_1))
    print(final_list)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```